# Help solving the Rydberg formula for 2 sets of 2 integers that both equal the same wavelength

Tags: equation-solving

The Rydberg formula:

[image]

I need to find a 2 sets of initial and final quantum numbers that return the same wavelength. To do this, I wrote some code and used the `Solve` function, but it keeps returning an empty set even when I use 2 values that I know work! Could someone help me out?

2 working sets of quantum numbers in the form {$n_i$, $n_f$}: {32, 28} {224, 56}

```
nf1 = 28 
ni1 = 32

rconst = 1.097*10^(7)

val1 = Rationalize[1/(rconst*((1/(nf1)^2) - (1/(ni1)^2)))]

Solve[1/(x)^2 - 1/(y)^2 == val1 && x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y}, Integers]
```

Comment: Running `Reduce[1/(x)^2 - 1/(y)^2 == val1 && x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y}]` shows that `x` and `y` can't both be integers.

Comment: This gives the possible values for `y` for the possible integer solutions for `x`:`Table[25 Sqrt[16455] Sqrt[-(x^2/(-10284375 + 3136 x^2))], {x, 1, 
   57}] // N`, as you can see, no integers.

Comment: But that seems kinda strange. The 2 working sets of quantum numbers actually do give the same wavelength and all 4 numbers are integers.

Comment: Well, could be a rounding issue for `R`.

Answer (score 2):

The Rydberg constant doesn't matter here, so

```
f[nf_, ni_] := 1/nf^2 - 1/ni^2
```

We can see that indeed the exemplary pair fulfills the condition of equal wavelengths:

```
f @@ {32, 28}
```

> -(15/50176)

```
f @@ {224, 56}
```

> -(15/50176)

---

This surely can be solved in a fancy and very fast way, but I'll use a brute force:

```
tab = Table[{{i, j}, {k, m}, f[i, j] == f[k, m]},
       {i, 28}, {j, i + 1, 32}, {k, 56}, {m, k + 1, 224}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {28.4311, Null}

```
tab2 = Flatten[tab, 3]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.3444, Null}

Solutions are in the form

```
tab2[[1]]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, True}

This one is rather trivial, though.

There are

```
Length@tab2
```

> 5364520

entries in `tab2`; we need to filter out those that make some sense:

```
sel = Select[tab2, Last@# == True && #[[1]] != #[[2]] &]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {5.31091, Null}

```
TableForm[sel, TableDepth -> 2]
```

[image]

There's a number of solutions for this problem.